# How to use pure Java in web applications without JavaScript knowledge?

Tags: java, javascript, web-applications, web

I love Java like hell. This is not my 'native' language in work and I do Java projects from time to time after work. I have used only few technologies with Java like communication via raw sockets and Swing. Once in the past I run the Apache-Tomcat with very simple JSP generated page. Really basic stuff.

Some time ago I was interviewed to participate in more commercial Java project. It was a web-service based on browser content/application... I heard words like 'JSON', 'GWT', 'AJAX', 'XML' and I was lost in answers. ... I suggested java Applets+Swing, but they wasn't interested. I realized I have extremely limited knowledge about web technologies. I looked very bad on this interview.

If I am not a JavaScript guy, can I really do web-apps with pure Java? I mean web pages with dynamic-fancy-elements which are I think provided mostly by the JavaScript. What technologies should I get to know? Can be JavaScript generated from Java code?

Comment: Learn Javascript. It's really not that hard, especially if you already know a programming language.

Comment: While you *can* do browser apps without understanding JavaScript (see the CW answer I posted), frankly, disliking a tool isn't really an excuse for not using the right tool for the job. And this is completely subjective, but I find that most folks I know who come to JavaScript from Java, C++, or other fairly strict languages initially don't like JavaScript because they find the looseness confusing...and then they learn to love the freedom. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll make this a CW answer, because the question isn't a fit for Stack Overflow's "one right answer" format.

Yes, you can write browser applications without knowing JavaScript. One way to do that is to use the [Google Web Toolkit](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/). *(Amusingly, this was one of the acronyms you heard but didn't know — GWT.)*

Comment: Never seen this before seems pretty cool

Answer (score 1):

**Why we need Javascript?**

to reduce load on the server, by doing things like input validations before submitting the data to server.

**Can all this be done without Javascript?**

Yes, you can have plain HTML and do all the validation from your Java code

**Is it good idea?**

No its not. By doing so, you are loading the server for simple tasks such as input validations which can be easily accomplished by Javascripts.

**I don't know Javascript. With ONLY Java can I get rich web-app?**

Yes, [GWT](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/) is google's tool which allows you to achieve the same. GWT gives you Eclipse plugins to manager the GWT web-apps and it allows you to write plain Java code (absolutely no Javascript) and in the backgroud coverts them into Javascript, so that the rich UI is created with most of the UI event handling in the browser itself.

Comment: Input validations should **always** be performed on the server side. And most of the time it is good practice to have it on client side as well. (Not the downvoter).

Answer (score 1):

From someone who has Java as their go too language, develops web applications and doesn't particularly like JavaScript I'd say... just learn JavaScript. Sure it's not a very nice language (IMHO) but it's absolutely essentially now-a-days. JavaScript appears just about everywhere now from JavaFX to web services (e.g. JSON) to web applications. Java has a JavaScript engine in [Rhino](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhino_%28JavaScript_engine%29) and is getting a new one in Java 8 called [Nashorn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nashorn_%28JavaScript_engine%29) so I'd expect to see more JavaScript not less.

In direct answer to your question, yes, you could write a web application without knowing any JavaScript but before long you'll find a situation where you *have* to hack on some JS or debug it and then you'll kick yourself for not having learnt it from the start.

Comment: JavaFX is interesting. It looks like something which could be cool for me. It is similar to QML I think. But I don't understand where is downside of JavaFX? There is not too many sites which run the JFX. Please correct me I am wrong.

Comment: JavaFX is great if you are a building an application to be run on the client machine. Technically it can be run in a browser I believe but it's very uncommon, there is a sort of half way house called web start which might be of interest to you. Web start runs the application locally but allows it to start from a web page. Honestly though, you need to learn JavaScript.

Comment: I just start with JNLP/JavaFX and have some more filling about the approach. The downside I think is security privileges which must be confirmed with such Web start (browser poput window). If something is written in Javascript there is no such popout/confirmation. The JavaScript must have some limited access to machine resources.

Answer (score 0):

To give a short answer, Yes you can but then the Javascript will be generated for you. There are many frameworks that will generate the Javascript for you. Maybe you should look at Vaadin if you don't like writting javascript at all.

On most projects there is no need for writting javascript on scratch. 99% of time we use jQuery or plugins based on those. Maybe you should have a look at the Twitter bootstrap.